# Ubuntu 23.10 Stuck on splash screen HP pavilian 8th i7 with AMD card

Tags: boot, drivers, display, 23.10

I have installed a default dual boot with windows 11 and then ubuntu 23.10

My Laptop has an i7 8th gen and an amd radeon graphics card ( HP pavilion series)
When i bootup ubuntu , it gets stuck at the splash screen and i cannot go any further

I found out that using the recovery mode and then editing the grub conf to have nomodeset ( or press e and manually add it) will remove the splash screen and solve my issue.

My problem is that using nomodeset causes my graphics drivers to not function properly and i cannot hook my secondary monitor through the hdmi port in my laptop. Furthermore, i cannot change the screen resolution of my primary laptop display , as it does not show a drop down menu to change resolution or refresh rate etc.

I have run vramdr in terminal and it gives me an error , remember i am on nomodeset. I have updated and upgraded everything using sudo apt-get update etc and have check the ubuntu addition drivers app and it shows nothing more is to be installed

I have searched the web a lot for any solution to this , having nomodeset off and then running my ubuntu distro normally so it can do normal stuff ( my second monitor does show the splash screen , but it gets stuck, confirming that nomodeset needs to be disabled).

Can someone please link or guide me, this is the default most configuration for ubuntu and its quite shocking honestly that ubuntu fails to bootup on a mainstream laptop with default settings